# How can i go to a new designed Form in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new in C# and also in this website ;)
I have a form and there is a Next button in it, I want to go to another form by clicking the Next Button, and I want to have some objects like text box or combox in a new form.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add a click event handler to your 'Next' button by double-clicking it in the designer.
Suppose your second form is called Form2. Create an instance of Form2 and use the Show method:

```
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a new form with controls like this

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        Form Form2 = new Form();
        Form2.Show();

        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        Form2.Controls.Add(txt1);
        Form2.Controls.Add(combo);
    }
```